# 3D-Touch changing line-width of CGContext - crossing lines is buggy

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cgcontext, 3dtouch

[image]

I want to change the width of the line with 3D-touch while drawing. I'm using the library ACEDrawingView which uses this code to draw:

```
- (void)draw
{
   CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

   CGContextAddPath(context, path);
   CGContextSetLineCap(context, kCGLineCapRound);
   CGContextSetLineWidth(context, self.lineWidth);
   CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, self.lineColor.CGColor);
   CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeNormal);
   CGContextSetAlpha(context, self.lineAlpha);
   CGContextStrokePath(context);
}
```

I use this code to change the lineWidth based on the pressure in touchesMoved:

```
// save all the touches in the path
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

//3d touch
CGFloat maximumPossibleForce = touch.maximumPossibleForce;
CGFloat force = touch.force;
CGFloat normalizedForce = force/maximumPossibleForce;
CGFloat lineWidth = normalizedForce * 10;
self.currentTool.lineWidth = lineWidth;
```

It all works good until I draw another line which crosses the previous one. Then it looks like the image above.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Please ask for more code if needed, or take a quick look at ACEDrawingView. Thank you!